# Include scss path for server side rendering with webpack

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-universal

I am trying to deploy the Angular Universal for my Angular 5 application (recently migration from Angular 4) and I encountered an issue with server side rendering option:

```
ng build --aot --app 1
```

My path for variables in scss files worked in client side but not on the server side rendering command. I received the error like this for `bootstrap-sass`

```
File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap/variable.
```

Change the path to specific path to the package in `node_modules` worked:

```
@import '~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/variables';
```

I needed to modify about 50 files that included `bootstrap/variable` but it still accepted. But my code also include a specific scss file and it varies from component to other component like this:

```
@import 'supergazol/footer';
```

I can go through about 50 files to change it accordingly to its path but it is not very effective and time consuming. Is there any way to tell Webpack to find the correct path?

My Angular CLI config for this path didn't work:

```
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
        "includePaths": [
          "../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets",
          "../src/style/supergazol",
          "../src/style"
        ]
      },
```

Folder structure:

```
src
    app
    assets
    environments
    style
```

Comment: What is the root setting for your app, in your angular-cli.json?

Comment: currently at `"root": "src"`

Comment: Can you show your folder hierarchy? especially for the style folder

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: and in your style folder, you have a supergazol folder, which contains a '_footer.scss' file ? What arror you do get exactly?

Comment: yes, it is. I got the same errors it cannot reach the variable files on server side rendering

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164832/discussion-between-david-and-tho-vo).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, it might help. I think you need to have it in both your apps in the .angular-cli.json file (for both the client and server app).

```
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
        "includePaths": [
          "../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets",
          "/style/supergazol",
          "style"
        ]
      },
```

Comment: For **"both apps"** clarification, in Angular 7 this means in the same ```angular.json``` file, add "stylePreprocessorOptions" to the "server" node at: projects > project-name > architect > server